# Call an API residing in Kubernetes from ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-aks

I have deployed an API with certain business logic in AKS. The load balancer type is internal. I am able to access this within AKS cluster. on the below address

```
http:servicename/myapi/
```

But I want to call this API from an ADF pipeline. How can I do that?  What are the configurations I should do to be able to call this API from ADF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Web Activity` to make Rest API call from Azure DataFactory  Pipeline.

> An Azure Data Factory may be used to call a custom REST endpoint
> through Web Activity. You can send datasets and connected services to
> the activity to be consumed and accessed.

**Note :** By utilizing self-hosted integration runtime, Web Activity may also invoke URLs that are hosted on a private virtual network. The URL endpoint should be visible to the integration runtime.

Please check below documentation to know more about web activity : [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) in Azure Datafactory.